# How to make python 3.9.1 my default version on MacOs

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, terminal, pip

I am trying to make Python version 3.9.1 my default python version. When I type “python —version” into terminal, it returns Python 2.7.16.

"whereis python3 returns "/usr/bin/python3". So, I change the alias with “alias python=/usr/local/bin/python3”. This temporarily sets my version to python3. In terminal, “python —version” returns "Python 3.9.1" and I can run Python 3.9.1 in the terminal by typing "python". Great.

However, this change is temporary. If I exit the shell and reenter, or open a new tab, I have to repeat the process. How do I make this permanent?

Also, will this cover everything on my OS that points to Python 2? For instance, will pip now point to Python3 and not 2?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest to use `pyenv` (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for managing differrent python versions on your machine. Other system programs which depends on py2 may break if you just relink `python` command to new version.